# Function for getting full directory structure

Tags: python

I need a function to recursively crawl directory for a list files, dirs, which will later be used in a mini file manager on site. I know how to do it, but I want to save time and to use function, if any.

Can you tell where to find a function or suggest options for implementation, because now I have only one option is to create a bypass structure with `os.walk`, and then checking for `isfile`, `isdir`, as you know, there are also files without extension.

Output can be like this (dict)

```
{
    "base_path": "c:\\my\\folder\\22\22\\2\\",
    "images": [
        "mini.jpg",
        "who_are_you.png",
        "i_m_Red_John.gif"
    ],
    "js": [
        "and_who_are_you.jQuery.js", 
        "im_Patrick_Jane.js"
    ],
    "index.html",
    "ahaha.htm"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to check. `os.walk` always returns a tuple in a form:

```
(current_directory, directory_list, files_list)
```

So you always know that the second element of the tuple is a list of directories found in the `current_directory`, and that the third element is a list of files found in the `current_directory`.

You should use `os.walk` in that manner:

```
for current, directories, files in os.walk(path):
   # do your stuff...
```

Comment: No, i know it, but look, this code `for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.join('sth_path', str(3))): print root, dirs, files` return sth like this 
`sth_path\3 ['images'] ['page.htm', 'styles.css']`
`sth_path\3\images [] ['rss.gif', 'Thumbs.db']` 
At first, I want generate list like this 
`['\\3\\images', '\\3\\page.htm', '\\3\\styles.css', '\\3\\images', '\\3\\images\\rss.gif', '\\3\\images\\Thumbs.db']`
And check everyone file for `isdir`, `isfile` and buid dict like in my question

Comment: Then you should rewrite your question a little bit better. And explain what kind of structure you want to get generated. The current structure is not a valid one because it doesn't support two levels of directories. How would you represent in your structure the case where you have in the `images` subfolder another subfolder `figures`. You should be more precise :)